# Choose Date jquery with form

Tags: jquery, forms, date

I just want to be able to choose 3 different dates with jquery using forms and send their values  with post.

This is my code:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    Date <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date1" />
    or <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date2" />
    to <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date3" />
</form>
<input style="height: 10px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 0;" name="maquinas" type="submit" value="visualizar" />
<input name="inicio" type="submit" value="INICIO" /> 
<input name="articulos" type="submit" value="ARTÍCULOS" /> 
<input name="averias" type="submit" value="AVERÍAS" />
</form>
```

The problem is that on my browser I only can choose one date with the datepicker.

Comment: use different name for id

Comment: provide us an example with jsfiddle or similar

Comment: can you provide  a jsfiddle

Comment: With different id the problem is the same.

Comment: Use class instead of ID, ID can only be unique per page

Comment: try with this example http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fdx9t8du/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per the Web Strategy you have to use only 1 ID per page since the ID is the Unique Element.

Use the code like this provided below.

```
<form action="#" method="post"> Date <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1" /> or <input type="text" id="date2" name="date2" /> to <input type="text" id="date3" name="date3" /></form> <input style="height: 10px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 0;" name="maquinas" type="submit" value="visualizar" /> <input name="inicio" type="submit" value="INICIO" /> <input name="articulos" type="submit" value="ARTÍCULOS" /> <input name="averias" type="submit" value="AVERÍAS" /> </form>

<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#date1').datepicker(); $('#date2').datepicker(); $('#date3').datepicker(); }); </script>
```

Comment: Optimize selectors: `$('#date1, #date2, #date3').datepicker()`

Comment: Sure will do it from here on . Thanks for rectifying me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of ID, because only first occurrence of ID will be used in JS code, other same ID elements will be ignored.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  
  $('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    
    $.ajax({
      url: self.attr('action'),
      type: self.attr('method'),
      data: self.serialize(),
      success: function () {
        alert('Success');
      },
      error: function () {
        alert('Fiddle does not allow ajax'+"\r\n"+'Data submitted: '+self.serialize());
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="#" method="post">Date
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date1" />or
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date2" />to
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date3" />
  <input style="height: 10px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 0;" name="maquinas" type="submit" value="visualizar" />
  <input name="inicio" type="submit" value="INICIO" />
  <input name="articulos" type="submit" value="ARTÍCULOS" />
  <input name="averias" type="submit" value="AVERÍAS" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post">FECHA: 
   <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date1" />
   <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date1" />
</form>
```

then Change your function

```
$( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
      } );
```